# "Boot" has 0 bytes

Tags: boot, kernel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free up more space on /boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/free-up-more-space-on-boot)

```
The volume "boot" has only 0 bytes disk space remaining.

You can free up disk space by removing unused programs or files, or by moving files to another disk or partition.
```

This is what I have in "boot":

```
/boot/abi-2.6.32-21-generic
/boot/abi-2.6.32-22-generic
/boot/abi-2.6.32-24-generic
/boot/abi-2.6.32-25-generic
/boot/abi-2.6.32-26-generic
/boot/abi-2.6.32-27-generic
/boot/abi-2.6.32-28-generic
/boot/abi-2.6.32-30-generic
/boot/abi-2.6.32-31-generic
/boot/abi-2.6.32-32-generic
/boot/abi-2.6.32-33-generic
/boot/config-2.6.32-21-generic
/boot/config-2.6.32-22-generic
/boot/config-2.6.32-24-generic
/boot/config-2.6.32-25-generic
/boot/config-2.6.32-26-generic
/boot/config-2.6.32-27-generic
/boot/config-2.6.32-28-generic
/boot/config-2.6.32-30-generic
/boot/config-2.6.32-31-generic
/boot/config-2.6.32-32-generic
/boot/config-2.6.32-33-generic
/boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-21-generic
/boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-22-generic
/boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-24-generic
/boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-25-generic
/boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-26-generic
/boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-27-generic
/boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-28-generic
/boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-30-generic
/boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-31-generic
/boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-32-generic
/boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-33-generic
/boot/memtest86+.bin
/boot/System.map-2.6.32-21-generic
/boot/System.map-2.6.32-22-generic
/boot/System.map-2.6.32-24-generic
/boot/System.map-2.6.32-25-generic
/boot/System.map-2.6.32-26-generic
/boot/System.map-2.6.32-27-generic
/boot/System.map-2.6.32-28-generic
/boot/System.map-2.6.32-30-generic
/boot/System.map-2.6.32-31-generic
/boot/System.map-2.6.32-32-generic
/boot/System.map-2.6.32-33-generic
/boot/vmcoreinfo-2.6.32-21-generic
/boot/vmcoreinfo-2.6.32-22-generic
/boot/vmcoreinfo-2.6.32-24-generic
/boot/vmcoreinfo-2.6.32-25-generic
/boot/vmcoreinfo-2.6.32-26-generic
/boot/vmcoreinfo-2.6.32-27-generic
/boot/vmcoreinfo-2.6.32-28-generic
/boot/vmcoreinfo-2.6.32-30-generic
/boot/vmcoreinfo-2.6.32-31-generic
/boot/vmcoreinfo-2.6.32-32-generic
/boot/vmcoreinfo-2.6.32-33-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-21-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-22-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-24-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-25-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-26-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-27-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-28-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-30-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-31-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-32-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-33-generic
```

Can I delete these?  I have not deleted these yet because I don't want to restart to find that I have lost my install...

I am using Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/is-there-a-way-to-remove-hide-old-kernel-versions/4284#4284) is a script to remove old kernels

Comment: Looks like Computer Janitor is the answer.  I will give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: People don't like Computer Janitor too much, because this application is sometimes too generous in removing things ;)

Comment: You're right it's not that good, especially as it is not listing any of the old kernels...